# How to correctly put array as an argument in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a Fortran function like below,

```
subroutine f(i,weight)
integer(kind=i8) :: i
real(kind=r8) :: weight(i,i)
return 
end
```

The matrix weight is a i by i matrix, and i is also an argument.

I want the same thing in Julia, I did below

```
function f(i::Int64, weight::Array{Float64,2}(undef,i,i))
return nothing
end
```

However it just give me an error,

```
UndefVarError: i not defined
```

But if I just do below without the weight matrix as an argument, it does not give error,

```
function f(i::Int64)
return nothing
end
```

But obviously this is not what I want.

Or, the following also no error,

```
function f(i::Int64, weight::Array{Float64,2})
return nothing
end
```

But this is not what I want. I want the weight matrix in the argument have particular dimensions i by i.

Do I have to do things like

```
function f(i::Int64, weight::Array{Float64,2})
weight = Array{Float64,2}(undef,i,i)
return nothing
end
```

But again, I want the weight in the argument have the i by i definition. How to do that in Julia?

Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Why pass `i` as an argument? Why not just get it from the size of the matrix? `i = size(weight, 1)` should do the trick.

Comment: @tholy Not really, it is just an illustration code. Int64 i have other use. The array weight have to be (i,i) size. it is also kind of a protection. In this example, you cannot put any array in the argument, it has to be (i,i) size.   i needs to be determined first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard `Array` does not have its size as a part of type specification. If you want this feature use https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl instead.

However, most of the time it is just enough to write:

```
function f(i::Int, weight::Matrix{Float64})
    @assert size(weight) == (i, i)
end
```

This time the check is made within a function and not at method dispatch time, but typically this is enough.

If you strictly would require the the behavior you want at dispatch time then the method signature using https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl would be:

```
function f(i::Val{T}, weight::SMatrix{T, T, Float64}) where T::Int
end
```

Note that I need to wrap `i` in `Val` to make sure the number passed is available to the compiler and is not only a run-time value.

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, could you please me know where can I find those @ tricks? I see you used @ assert size, sometimes I also see @eval, etc. But not sure where to find a place such that all the usage of @ is duscussed.

Comment: Probably there is no single place. `@` signals a macro, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#man-macros. They can be found in the Julia manual the same way as functions can be found - in the parts of the documentation where they fit (there is nothing in-built with `@` - you can define your own macros also).